# Proving that charge distributes uniformly on a sphere using only Coulomb's law and math

Tags: electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law, differential-equations

So we know that charge distributes uniformly on a conducting sphere, or shell for that matter; there's no other way for it, as it's so symmetrical that no other argument would work. However, I'm trying to prove this fact using Coulomb's law, because I want to use the same technique for another problem that is only symmetrical about a line.

Now, all I have is that from the bottom of the sphere to its top, charge is symmetrically distributed on every ring and the total charge equals to $Q$, so:
$$
\int_{-R}^{R}2\pi R\sigma_{(z)}dz= Q
$$
And that the total field created by every ring on the sphere equals to zero on every point of it (here, the point h above it's centre), so:
$$
E_{h} = \int_{-R}^{R}\frac{2\pi RK\sigma_{(z)}(z-h)dz}{(R^2+h^2-2hz)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = 0
$$
I've used the formula for the electric field of a uniformly charged ring in the last one which on a point of z above it's centre is:
$$
E_{z} = \frac{2\pi RK\lambda z}{(R^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
$$
And I've just made it a little neater. And if it helps, we know that:
$$
\int\frac{(z-h)dz}{(R^2+h^2-2hz)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = \frac{R^2-hz}{\sqrt{R^2+h^2-2hz}}
$$
Which when $h<R$ from $-R$ to $R$ equals to $0$.

Now, to sum it all up, using the first two equations, I want to prove that:
$$
\sigma_{(z)} = \frac{Q} {4\pi R^2}
$$
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If you aren’t willing to assume that charge is symmetrically distributed on the sphere, why are you willing to assume that “charge is symmetrically distributed on every ring”? Why aren’t you starting with a general distribution $ \sigma(\theta,\phi)$?

Comment: @Ghoster Yeah, that would be a more general and preferred situation but I'm going to use this technique in another problem which has a line of symmetry. I didn't want to further complicate the situation but that helps as well and might even be better.